# How to increase ftrace precision to microseconds?

Tags: linux, android, debugging, trace

I'm trying to generate FTrace files inside an Android environment, using:

```
root@adroid:# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable
root@adroid:# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
root@adroid:# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace > mytracefile.txt
root@adroid:# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on
root@adroid:# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable
```

The problem is that in `mytracefile.txt` the precision of time stamp is in milliseconds:

```
          <idle>-0     [000] d.h7 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=tfm_b6bcf800 pid=1714 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=000
          <idle>-0     [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/0 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 next_pid=1714 next_prio=35
    tfm_b6bcf800-1714  [000] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=tfm_b6bcf800 prev_pid=1714 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D|W ==> next_comm=swapper/0 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=D ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.690000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
 Player Aud Mixe-146   [001] d..3 14186.690000: sched_switch: prev_comm=Player Aud Mixe prev_pid=146 prev_prio=35 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=swapper/1 next_pid=0 next_prio=120
          <idle>-0     [001] d.h3 14186.700000: sched_wakeup: comm=Player Aud Mixe pid=146 prio=35 success=1 target_cpu=001
          <idle>-0     [001] d..3 14186.700000: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/1 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=Player Aud Mixe next_pid=146 next_prio=35
```

Normally, it should be in the order of microseconds, like 14186.691234 instead of just 14186.690000.

I have already tested all the other `trace_clock` options that I have (local, global and counter) but the results are always the same. Changing that parameter doesn't change anything in the output file.

I followed carefully [FTrace documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) but I don't know what else to change in configuration.

Searching over the internet I had only been able to find this bug report but it was not solved: http://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-dev/2011-February/002720.html

Any advice?

Are there additional modules in the kernel that I have to install?

- Android Version: 4.2.2
- Kernel Linux Version: 3.4.7

`dmesg` output is also showing milliseconds precision:

```
<4>[   38.130000] oom_adj 0 => oom_score_adj 0
<4>[   38.130000] oom_adj 1 => oom_score_adj 58
<4>[   38.140000] oom_adj 2 => oom_score_adj 117
<4>[   38.140000] oom_adj 4 => oom_score_adj 235
<4>[   38.150000] oom_adj 9 => oom_score_adj 529
<4>[   38.150000] oom_adj 15 => oom_score_adj 1000
```

### Update:

We are building a graphic parser for android ftrace files (including **atrace** traces). That's why it is very important to have as much precision as possible.

Using the same device and other software tools we can successfully have microseconds precision.

So, now we're planning to edit **ftrace.c** source code to modify the way timestamp is generated to this one:

```
static inline uint64_t my_custom_jiffies(void)
{
         struct timeval tv;
         gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
         return tv.tv_sec*1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
}
```

I personally think that is not a very good solution/architecture/implementation because this should be possible without modifying the source code... but it's the only idea that we have at this moment.

What do you think ?

Comment: You listed a symptom as the problem. What is the issue this is causing? Like what are you workflow are you engaged in that that gets stopped by the lower precision? Are you trying to match times and several events land within the same second? Just something you noticed? etc.

Comment: The kernel can't provide timers any more accurate than the underlying hardware supports. Do you know for a fact that your Android device provides a microsecond timer? There's a good chance it doesn't, on purpose, because that flies directly in the face of battery savings, one of the primary hardware design drivers for such devices.

Comment: @WarrenYoung I'm seeing that the available clock options includes one ("uptime") denominated in jiffies, wouldn't that necessary give the OP more granularity (albeit granularity that varies depending on platform and not the level the OP may be going for)? I'm trying to understand the subject a little more.

Comment: @JoelDavis, Jiffies are usually on the order of 1-10 mS.  They are the original unit of the main PC periodic timer interrupt, which you define with the HZ kernel config.  Higher resolution timers requires a special feature of the cpu, like the HPET.

Comment: @JoelDavis: You're still thinking at the Linux kernel API level. I want someone to point me to a datasheet for this phone/tablet/whatever SoC that shows me the hardware register containing the microsecond timer.

Comment: JoelDavis and @WarrenYoung thank you very much for your help, I've updated the post to answer your questions. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this issue has nothing to do with Android. We have tested with our custom Linux version and we have still the same problem: **FTrace** produces milliseconds precision while other tools are able to produce microseconds precision. Maybe a FTrace module version problem?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

By default ftrace uses whatever the "sched_clock()" code uses. But you can change the ftrace clock in the /sys/kernel/tracing/trace_clock file. On x86 I have:

```
# cat /sys/kernel/tracing/trace_clock 
[local] global counter uptime perf mono mono_raw boot x86-tsc
```

The "local" clock is the sched_clock() equivalent. But I can chose other clocks by echoing it. If I want the x86-tsc as my clock I would do:

```
# echo x86-tsc > /sys/kernel/tracing/trace_clock
```

The architecture code can add new clock by defining ARCH_TRACE_CLOCKS. See how x86-tsc was created, in arch/x86/include/asm/trace_clock.h.